# Javascript Sliding Divs Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have two forms on the same page and I want to show only one form when the page loads and other form should only be visible when a link is clicked. I have tried many methods but failed every single time. I don´t know much about JS or jquery and any help would be appreciated. Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c73bjypu/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#slide_btn_1').on('click', function(){
        if($('#form_cont_one').css('form_content_one') == '0px') {
            $('#form_cont_one').animate({'form_cont_one': '-105%'});
            $('#form_cont_two').animate({'form_cont_one': '0px'});
        } else {
            $('#form_cont_one').animate({'form_cont_one': '0px'});
            $('#form_cont_two').animate({'form_cont_one': '105%'});
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c73bjypu/3/):

```
$('#slide_btn_1').on('click', function(){
    if($('#form_cont_one').css('left') == '0px') {
        $('#form_cont_one').animate({'left': '-100%'});
        $('#form_cont_two').animate({'left': '0px'});
    } else {
        $('#form_cont_one').animate({'left': '0px'});
        $('#form_cont_two').animate({'left': '-100%'});
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have two links for toggling the forms. I want to show "form two" when slide_btn_2 is clicked and want to show "Form 1" when slide_btn_1 is clicked. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/c73bjypu/3/

Comment: There is neither a slide_btn_1 nor a slide_btn_2 in your html.
Please try to understand the code (read the jquery-docs) and change it to your needs.

Comment: I guess I had forgotten to update the fiddle. It was at the very top: http://jsfiddle.net/c73bjypu/4/

Answer (score -1):

```
function pageLoad(){
$('#form_cont_one').show();

$('#form_cont_two').hide();
}

function onLinkClick(){
$('#form_cont_two').show();

}
```